# How to prove this property of the power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that $A\subseteq B$ iff $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$, were $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the power set.

Do you agree with my proof? To prove that $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$ implies $A\subseteq B\,$ let $\,x\in A$ be arbitrary element. Then $\{x\}$ must be in $P(A)$, thus $\{x\}$ must also be in $P(B)$ so $x\in B$. Also, I'm stuck with the second implication.

Comment: Minor nit, but it's "power set", not "powered set". I think "The Powered Set" was a rock band from the 1960s. :-)

Comment: sorry, my bad, I'm newbie in math.

Comment: No problem. Everyone knew what you meant. I just figure you'll look more professional if you learn the new terms 100% accurately. Plus I think questions get a better reception when readers don't have to stumble over figuring out small errors like that.

Comment: @laurab I've edited your post. The edit is currently under review, but when it is approved feel free to accept it or not.

Comment: thank all you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof for the $\Leftarrow$ implication is fine. As for the $\Rightarrow$ implication, let $E\in \mathcal{P}(A)$, then $E$ is a subset of $A$. For all $x\in E$ we have $x\in A$, thus also $x\in B$, so $E$ is also a subset of $B$ and thus $E\in \mathcal{P}(B)$.
Q.E.D.